# How to run multiple instances of uwp app

Tags: windows, uwp

Am trying to run multiple instances of "uwp" app in windows 10.
I did tried servals things by changing name
Tried to search may place still no clear answer or is it not possible

Comment: What app are you trying to start?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can run multiple instances of a given application normally depends on the application.

Some applications allow multiple instances, and some do not. There is not a "one size fits all" rule for this.

Please let us know what specific application you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

There are UWP apps that can be opened in multiple windows and others
that won’t open another instance no matter what.

Here are some methods that may work for some apps:

- Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>
  on the taskbar icon of the app. This works for Calculator, but not many
  others.
- Use right-click on the taskbar icon of the app and select the app name.
- Use middle-click on the taskbar icon of the app.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> while the app is active.
  This may work for some apps.

If none of the above work, then the UWP app was coded in such a way
that calling multiple instances is impossible.